# Как сделать так, чтобы список новых тегов был с новой строки?

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

Я ввожу: span*7, нажимаю tab, но у меня они почему-то в одну строку все.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы они были в столбец, каждый с новой строки?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы был перенос, строчный элемент надо сделать блочным

display:block;

Строчные элементы по умолчанию в строку идут, блочные друг под другом, если не писать иное в CSS (типа float)

А если вопрос именно форматирования касается, то либо написать сниппет свой или верстать блочными

Comment: Меня интересует только отображение в программе, так как когда оно в одну строку, не слишком удобно заполнять информацией

Comment: Если именно спаны надо, напишите сниппет)

Comment: пока не умею сниппеты делать. Подскажите в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Я умею в sublime text 3 делать, посмотрите документацию по пхпшторм. Чтобы как в эммет... ввели определенную комбинацию, нажали таб и раз... появился кусок кода)